# Want to reverse a range but I get back <range_iterator object at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>

Tags: python

I'm coding a connect "M" and I want to enumerate the rows starting with the biggest number (the last one). So I tried using reverse in my function but it print this `<range_iterator object at 0x0000017B4A49D7F0>`. Could anyone help me out?

Here's my code:

```
def print_board(self):
    # Number the columns separately to keep it cleaner
    print(end='  ')
    for r in range(BOARD_COLS):
        print(f"{r} ", end="")
    print("")

# Print the slots of the game board
for r in range(BOARD_ROWS):
    backwards = reversed(range(r))
    print(backwards, end="")
    print('', end="")
    for c in range(BOARD_COLS):
        print(f" {self.board[r][c]}", end="")
    print("")
```

Let's say that BOARD_ROWS = 7, I want to print the numbers starting from 7 all the way to 0.

Comment: why not generate range that way at start? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: `reversed` returns an iterator. If you want a list then you can create one using `list(reversed(range(r))`.

Comment: I can't reverse it from the start because my program, which is supposed to be a connect 4 type of game, instead of adding pieces to the bottom, when i reverse range(BOARD_ROWS) it adds pieces to the top.

Answer (score 2):

`reversed()` returns a `range` object.

Looking at your requirement, you want to print reverse numbers so you simply need to reverse the `range(BOARD_ROWS)`.

Here's how the code will look *(for the range part)*:

```
for r in reversed(range(BOARD_ROWS)): # iterates 6 to 0
    print(r) # 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 - this is index
    for c in range(BOARD_COLS):
        print(f" {self.board[r][c]}", end="")
    # you can add the print statements, didn't find them useful so removed it.
```

**Docs:**
[`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

Comment: _Technically_, `reversed` returns a reversed iterator. Since the input is a `range` in this case, it returns a `range_iterator`. `reversed` does _not_ return a `range` object, as can be verified by trying to access an attribute such as `.step`, which exists on a `range` but not on whatever `reversed(range(...))` returns.

Comment: I can't reverse it from the start because my program, which is supposed to be a connect 4 type of game, instead of adding pieces to the bottom, when i reverse range(BOARD_ROWS) it adds pieces to the top.

Comment: So, you can make a deepcopy using `copy.deepcopy()`. You might need to import `copy`.